# Generate a xml file during build process

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2013

Is there any way to generate a XML file during/after/before the build process in VS 2013?

It's basically my own manifest file, at least it should serve the same purpose (as click once).

Comment: You can run pre-build and post-build commands to generate whatever you want. I'm not sure I understand *how* this Xml file gets generated though, do you want some information inside of it automatically generated?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can call your own app (to create xml or anything) by configuring build events (pre/post build):

Project—>Properties—>Configuration Properties—>Build Events